# Meteor Github authorization

Tags: authorization, meteor, github-api

I am using the meteor accounts-github module to handle my authentication/account creation in my application.

I want to ensure that any new user who attempts to sign into the application is a member of a particular Github organisation. I also want to verify this not just when the user is first created, but on every sign in. If the user has been removed from this Github organisation then they should not be able to sign in to my application.

Essentially, I am adding some admin functionality to a website, and I only want Github users who are members of a particular organisation to be allowed to sign in and perform this admin functionality (such as update some basic content).

Is there a way to perform this Github API call on every user creation and sign in event?

Answer (score 2):

you will need to customize the authentication a bit, checkout my project:

https://github.com/534N/miProfile

I implemented it so that only github account is accepted.